# First element in Body tag is hard-stuck on top left corner

Tags: html, css

I've been having an issue with every single CSS exercise so far where the first element inside my body tag, whether it's an img or an h1 is simply stuck at the top left corner of the page (where the body tag starts, I assume) and it's just impossible to move it in any way, regardless of margin size or element width. I even tried adding a background color to it just to see if it would work and it didn't, so i guess that for some reasons, no modifications can be made to this element.

Here's my HTML

```
 <body>
    <header class="Top">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="NeoDance Logo" width="356" height="48" class="logo">

        <nav class="NavBar">
            <a href="" class="links">Home</a>
            <a href="" class="links">About</a>
            <a href="" class="links">Class schedules</a>
            <a href="" class="links">Performances</a>
            <a href="" class="links">Blog</a>
            <a href="" class="links">Contact</a>

        </nav>
        <div class="ClearFix"></div>

    </header>
```

Here's my CSS. Note that before this displayed line, I'm using a completely unedited version of the Meyer css reset

```
    header.Top{
    width: 1440px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #303030;
    overflow: hidden

}

div.wrapper

img.Logo{



    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #303030;



}

    nav.NavBar{
    float: right;
    width: 490px;
    background-color: #303030;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 250px

}

a.links{
    float: right;
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 18px;
}

div.container 1{
    width: 490px;
    clear: both
}

img.dancers{
    float: right;
}

div.ClearFix{
    clear: both;
}
```

That img.logo should  have margins applied, as specified in the css. However it's just stuck there, shown in the image below

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAz04.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about your logo, and not the actual `header` element.

For one, your css selector is wrong.  It should be `img.logo` instead of `img.Logo`

Also, remove that `div.wrapper` code from your css.  What's that doing there?  Then remove the `margin: auto` from your `img.logo` style and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that I was using Logo instead of logo. The wrapper thing was there because I hadn't put any info in it but I was going to use it. Anyway, your advice helped me solve the issue, thank you!

Comment: No problem.  Would you mind voting my answer up since it helped you?

Comment: I voted your answer, but since I'm a new member the vote isn't displayed

Answer (score 0):

The order of declaration in CSS is important (hence the "Cascading").

Therefore, when you do :

```
img.Logo{
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

`margin:auto` overrides all of the margins above.

You should try to put `margin:auto` before  the other margins and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, duly noted and the issue is now resolved!

Comment: You're welcome! May you pick the correct answer so that the question is marked as answered?